# how to compile nginx with ngx_http_headers_module

Tags: nginx

I found the reference on how to use the [ngx_http_headers_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) but nowhere how to compile Nginx with this module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a default module. You don't have to do anything to compile it, if you already have compiled nginx with http support.

Comment: In Nginx Alpine this module seems not to be added under /etc/nginx/modules however. And I do not get http status 201s back. Tried to add it with `--with-http_headers_module \`  at https://github.com/jasperf/nginx-alpine/blob/master/Dockerfile but it did not compile properly. Perhaps the module is stored elsewhere?